# How to pass certain arguments to a PowerShell cmdlet without repeating myself?

Tags: powershell

I need to call Invoke-RestMethod repetitively and some of the arguments will always be the same, e.g. the `Uri` and `Headers`. Can I save myself from writing `-Uri $uri -Headers $headers` all over again?

(If I wrapped it in a function, I wouldn't be able to call it with all the parameters that Invoke-RestMethod supports, would I?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use splatting:

```
$par = @{uri="$uri";headers="$headers"}

invoke-restmethod @par -credential $whatever
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're running V3 or better, you can use $PSDefaultParamterValues, and set those as the default values for those parameters of the Invoke-RestMethod command.